# does law defines any hacker rules?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, international, ethical-hacking

does law defines any limitation that tells how much can a hacker use his knowledge in different way?
Any boundary that tells about hacker and cracker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the law and belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hacker can refer to "white hat" hackers or "black hat" hackers, with the latter being the "bad" guys. Hacking is typically infiltrating a network for various reasons, while "cracking" is to remove license restrictions on particular software. I hope this is moved to English.SE or [Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as it would be much more appropriate there.

Comment: @RonBeyer Good points, although technically speaking "hacking" may also involve removal of restrictions (doing some "hack" in the code) and "cracking" typically also involves brute-forcing of credentials to infiltrate a network. In other words, *network vs. license restrictions* does not delimit the distinction between these two terms. It rather boils down to the motive for messing up with the system (irrespective of it being a network or an executable).

Comment: Adnan: I see you edited the question, but it is still off-topic as "too broad."  To get an idea of why, look at all of the questions tagged [tag:hacking].

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Difference between hacker and cracker. according to my teacher Hacker
>   is a good person and Cracker is a bad person? can anyone explain?

I agree this is not a question about law. Anyway ...

*Cracker* connotes a purpose of inflicting harm by taking advantage of system vulnerabilities that the person detected. A *hacker* also searches for vulnerabilities in a system, but the difference is that he would report them to the systems owner/programmer, or maybe even help with the solution.

I think the difference of meanings has not been formalized, though, which is why both terms often are used interchangeably.

Comment: @AdnanButt You're very welcome.

Comment: You agree it's off-topic and answer anyway? This contributes to more people asking off-topic questions, knowing that they'll get an answer anyway, and lowers quality.

Comment: @Nij Relax. When the post gets moved to another SE site, it will go with answer and all. No big deal.

Comment: @Nij i got my answer . it is my mistake to ask this question on wrong site. I'll delete this question.

Comment: @Nij I have edited my question to relation of Law . i also have this question on my mind . please check and guide me with your answer .